# How to import experiment data to an Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing my first experiment on `Python`. I have created my experiment using Psychopy and everything is working but I'm having problems to import the data from my experiment in `Python` to an Excel file.

My Excel file is blank once I'm done running my experiment. I will share the lines of code in which I try to import the data to Excel.

Thank you for your help!

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['answer', 'correctness', 'RT']) 
df.loc[csvcounter] = [user_response[0][0], correctness, user_response[0][1]] #[0],[0] ... [0][1]
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['answer', 'correctness', 'RT']) 
df.to_csv(FILE_DIR + r"/Experiment.csv")
```

Comment: This is incorrectly tagged as `r`, when it should be `python` and `excel`. And I believe you mean export, not import?

Comment: Yes, I've meant export and not import. I'm sorry. I think it may have tagged r because I've mentioned r as an interested.

Answer (score 1):

Your third line creates a new empty DataFrame and overwrites the variable with the filled DataFrame. Next, you write the empty DataFrame to a csv file.

---

Answer to question in the comments:
Depends how your experiment's data is structured. But here's an example for `numpy.ndarray`: Assume we got data with 1) the participants number, 2) their gender and 3) their age:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4], ['M', 'F', 'F', 'M'], [18, 21, 35, 27]]).T
```

so data now looks like this:

```
array([['1', 'M', '18'],
       ['2', 'F', '21'],
       ['3', 'F', '35'],
       ['4', 'M', '27']], ='<U11')
```

now we create an empty DataFrame similar to what  you did:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'number':[], 'gender':[], 'age':[]})
```

and write the `ndarray` to it:

```
df[['number', 'gender', 'age']] = data
```

And if you write this DataFrame to a file it should contain the 4 people:

```
df.to_csv(FILE_DIR + r"/Experiment.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you Jurgy!

Do you know how I could write the data from my experiment in that empty csv file?